# Como verificar se já é outro dia?

Tags: java, time

Estou fazendo uma aplicação em que uma funcionalidade fica disponível até que uma condição seja atingida, depois disso eu tenho que desabilitar a funcionalidade e só habilitá-la no outro dia.

Como sei que já é outro dia?

Comment: Qual é a versão do Java que você está usando?

Comment: Qual o periodo do dia que você precisa deixar disponivel?

Comment: Na verdade é o dia todo, a funcionalidade vai ser desabilitada qnd uma condição for atingida. A versão é 1.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Você pode verificar de diversas maneiras,tais como :**

> 24h em Milissegundos => 24 (h) * 60 (minutos) * 60 (segundos) * 1000 (Milissegundos) para que você possa apenas verificar se a diferença entre as datas em milissegundos é maior do que 86.400.000.

Ou adicionar o seguinte código para verificar :

```
public static final long ONE_MINUTE = 60 * 1000; // Criando uma variável static para dizer que um minuto em milissegundos equivale a 60.000;

public static final long ONE_HOUR = 60 * ONE_MINUTE; // Criando uma variável static para dizer que uma hora em milissegundos equivale a 3.600.000;

public static final long ONE_DAY = 24 * ONE_HOUR;// Criando uma variável static para dizer que 24 horas em milissegundos equivale a 86.400.000;

public static boolean isYesterday(Date d)//Criando uma classe Date chamada d {
    return DateUtils.isToday(d.getTime() + ONE_DAY);//O método getTime() retorna o número de milissegundos desde 1 de janeiro de 1970, 00:00:00 GMT representado por este objeto Date.
}
```

Para melhor entendimento aconselho você a dar uma olhada na documentação oficial da Oracle sobre o assunto,[aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html),[aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) e [aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date()).

**Você pode também usar [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) que segundo a documentação deles :**

> A data e hora normal nas versões anteriores para Java SE 8 são pobres. Ao abordar este problema de frente, Joda-Time tornou-se de fato o padrão para data e hora sobre a biblioteca para Java antes do Java SE 8. Note que a partir de Java SE 8 em diante, os usuários são convidados a migrar para java.time (JSR-310) - uma parte essencial do JDK que substitui este projeto.

**Mas afinal por que usar Joda-Time ?**

> A produtividade aumentará muito com o uso de uma biblioteca que lhe forneça resultados simples para processos que antes eram considerados complexos.
>
> Proporciona melhor performance do que a classe Calendar, usualmente utilizada para fins de manipulação de datas. Isso ocorre devido ao mínimo de cálculo realizado no acesso de algum campo.
>
> Possui vasta comunidade e documentação para auxiliar-lhe em dúvidas ou problemas que possam ocorrer.
>
> Cálculos de Time Zone são atualizados várias vezes por ano, para garantir consistência dos dados. Estes são atualizados a partir de http://www.iana.org/time-zones
>
> Possui métodos mais simples do que a classe Calendar.
>
> É Open-source, isso significa que qualquer um pode estudar seu código fonte e contribuir se achar relevante.

**Para poder usar o Joda-Time,faça o seguinte :**

> 1 º Baixe [neste link](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time) a biblioteca Joda-Time.
>
> 2º Para usar o Joda-Time em seu projeto basta adicionar o jar da seção de downloads no classpath do seu projeto.
>
> 3º Para importar as classes do Joda-Time use a seguinte referência :

```
import org.joda.time.classeQueVoceQuerImportar
```

> OBS : Caso estiver utilizando a versão 1.8 do jdk, não precisa importar a lib do Joda-Time pois ela já faz parte do java, através do pacote java.time.

**Usando o Joda-Time :**

Adicione o seguinte código,quando usando Joda-Time :

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Sao_Paulo" );
DateTime dateTimeInQuestion = new DateTime( 2016, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, timeZone );  // Or: new DateTime( someJavaDotUtilDotDateObject );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime twentyFourHoursFromNow = now.plusHours( 24 ); // Ignores Daylight Saving Time (DST). If you want to adjust for that, call: plusDays( 1 ) instead.
DateTime isDateTimeInQuestionAfter24HoursFromNow = dateTime.isAfter( twentyFourHoursFromNow );
```

Dê uma olhada [neste link](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) para você poder ver a lista de fuso horário do Joda-Time para caso quiser mudar.

Comment: Seria interessante explicar o que este código(do java.time) está fazendo, caso o OP não conheça o funcionamento.

Comment: Gostaria de usar a 2 opção mas não entendi mt bem como funciona. Toda vez que abro a aplicação, chamo a função isYesterday passando a data atual como parâmetro?

Comment: @diegofm Sim é interessante,vou dar mais uma editada na pergunta.

Comment: @AmandaFagundes Sim você passa a data atual como parâmetro.

Comment: @Falion eu me referi ao modo com jodatime, que é mais recomendado para isso, porém, é mais complicado de se entender se não se está acostumado.

Comment: @diegofm Ok,vou também colocar uma resposta mais detalhada sobre o assunto.

Comment: Se estiver utilizando a versão 1.8 do jdk, não precisa importar essa lib do jodatime, pois ela já faz parte do java, através do pacote java.time.

Comment: @diegofm Obrigado pela informação,vou colocar ela também na resposta.